# Usar un Font personalizado - Android

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, fuentes

Estoy siguiendo este [tutorial](https://johnthiriet.com/xamarin-android-custom-font/?fbclid=IwAR0X08xvGGaf3vd3-UzBmv1Mrp9hhEWGSnJ_K3sDCrxHiyI0rOQKZ_r2Iv8) para cambiar las fonts de la app en Xamarin.Android, el tutorial va directo al punto, básicamente es agregar el archivo `.ttf` al proyecto en una carpeta llamada `fonts` dentro de `resources` y luego hacer referencia en el `TextView/EditText` o donde se quiera usar, de esta forma:

```
android:fontFamily="@font/sourcerfont"
```

[image: fonts]

El archivo sourcerfont.xml contine lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">   <font android:font="@font/futurab"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/futurab"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400" /> </font-family>
```

**El problema que estoy teniendo es que solo me funciona con los dispositivos que tienen al menos Android 8 o mayor, y no con los que tienen Android 5 o 6 por ejemplo.**

Volví a leer la documentación (el tutorial) y encontré esta parte que me llamo la atención, y me da la impresión que ahi podría estar el error:

> This feature is also supported on devices till Android 4.1 by using
> Support Library 26 or more.

[image: Imagen]

Me podrían indicar que estoy haciendo mal?

No creo que solo se pueda usar fonts personalizados en Android mayores al 8.

La única forma que me funciona en todos los dispositivos es esta pero es muy tedioso con apps grandes y necesito que sea desde XML:

```
                TextView Lbl = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Lbl34);
                tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets, "quicks.ttf");
                Lbl.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
```

Comment: ¿Que hay en el archivo font.xml?

Comment: Contiene una referencia a uno de los fonts que tengo descargados. Acabo de editar y agregar el archivo .xml para que lo puedan ver.

Comment: Estas usando visual studio?

Comment: Si, estoy usando Xamarin.Android - Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Tengo una pregunta, bastante tonta de hecho, en la línea `android:fontFamily="@font/sourcerfont"` ¿No funciona poner directamente la font `android:fontFamily="@font/antiqua.ttf` /  `android:fontFamily="@font/antiqua` ?

Comment: Si, si funciona, pero solo visible para los dispositivos Android 8+

Comment: He añadido una respuesta, me comentas si te ha servido @KennyAli

Comment: Que yo sepa android no tiene ningun problema, ya que la font que esta en la carpeta font se la usa en el attr de la vista y no en un xml aparte ya que la vista se encarga de hacer la compatibilidad con todas las versiones. No entiendo por que tienes un xml aparte y por codigo es complicadito

Comment: Me toco hacerlo desde código (C#) para que quedara para todos los dispositivos. Si llego a averiguar que paso, que era el error o como se logro solucionar se los hare saber.

Answer (score 2):

Ademàs de definir la fuente programaticamente puedes definirla directamente en la vista:

```
<TextView
  ...
  ...
  android:fontFamily="@font/quicks" />
```

Si estas realizando pruebas con dispositivosy el problema se presenta en dispositivos menores a Android 8, seguramente estas usando las libraries de soporte, por esta razòn seguramente necesitaràs declarar los certificados de los proveedores de fuentes.

Revisa lo que se comenta en este blog:

[Xamarin Android - Reference custom fonts in XML](https://johnthiriet.com/xamarin-android-custom-font/)

[**Definir los certificados del proveedor de fuentes**](https://johnthiriet.com/xamarin-android-custom-font/)

**Si está utilizando las bibliotecas de soporte, es necesario declarar los certificados de los proveedores de fuentes.**

El siguiente ejemplo es para Google Fonts. Si tiene otros proveedores, deberá agregar o actualizar los valores en consecuencia.

En la carpeta `Resouces/values`, cree un nuevo archivo `font_certs.xml`.
Asegúrese de que la acción de compilación del archivo esté configurada en AndroidResource.
Copie el siguiente xml dentro del archivo recién creado

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
        <item>@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_dev</item>
        <item>@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_prod</item>
    </array>
    <string-array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_dev">
        <item>
            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
        </item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_prod">
        <item>
            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
        </item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

---

Tu archivo  `sourcerfont.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font android:font="@font/quicks"
          android:fontStyle="normal"
          android:fontWeight="400"
          app:font="@font/quicks"
          app:fontStyle="normal"
          app:fontWeight="400" />
</font-family>
```

Comment: Ya volvi a rehacer el tutorial nuevamente, probe el método de font descargable, agregue los dos archivos a resources/values y agregue el meta-data en el Android Manifest. Aun nada. No funciona.

Comment: Y para aclarar tu respuesta, el error me sucede con android MENORES a Android 8, o sea Android 5, 6..

Comment: Asì es, si es menor a 8 seguramente usas las support libraries.

Answer (score 0):

¿Puedes probar editanto tu `sourcerfont.xml` para que quede de la siguiente manera?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<font-family 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/futurab"

        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/futurab"
    />
```

Comment: Ya lo intente pero aun nada, y no me extraña dado que es básicamente a como lo tenia. Solo me pidió agregar la  etiqueta de cierre al final: </font-family>

Answer (score -1):

Para **Android 4.1 (API level 16) y posteriores** debes hacerlo de esta manera:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/myfont-Regular"/>
    <font app:fontStyle="italic" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/myfont-Italic" />
</font-family>
```

JAVA:

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont);
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml#using-support-lib

Comment: No es java, es xamarín